# In PowerShell and Windows Forms, how to capture user-entered data using multiple dynamically created input controls

Tags: winforms, powershell

I have a script I need to use for multiple parameter data collection, as follows:

```
function Build-FormPanel($FormTitle){
    Add-Type -Assembly System.Windows.Forms     ## Load the Windows Forms assembly 
    ## Create the main form 
    $form = New-Object Windows.Forms.Form 

    $form.FormBorderStyle = "FixedToolWindow" 
    $form.Text = $FormTitle
    $form.AutoScroll = $True
    $form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen" 
    $form.Width = 740 ; $form.Height = 480  # Make the form wider 

    #Add Buttons- ## Create the button panel to hold the OK and Cancel buttons 
    $buttonPanel = New-Object Windows.Forms.Panel  
        $buttonPanel.Size = New-Object Drawing.Size @(400,40) 
        $buttonPanel.Dock = "Bottom"    
        $cancelButton = New-Object Windows.Forms.Button  
            $cancelButton.Top = $buttonPanel.Height - $cancelButton.Height - 10; $cancelButton.Left = $buttonPanel.Width - $cancelButton.Width - 10 
            $cancelButton.Text = "Cancel" 
            $cancelButton.DialogResult = "Cancel" 
            $cancelButton.Anchor = "Right" 
        ## Create the OK button, which will anchor to the left of Cancel 
        $okButton = New-Object Windows.Forms.Button   
            $okButton.Top = $cancelButton.Top ; $okButton.Left = $cancelButton.Left - $okButton.Width - 5 
            $okButton.Text = "Ok" 
            $okButton.DialogResult = "Ok" 
            $okButton.Anchor = "Right" 
        ## Add the buttons to the button panel 
        $buttonPanel.Controls.Add($okButton) 
        $buttonPanel.Controls.Add($cancelButton) 
    ## Add the button panel to the form 
    $form.Controls.Add($buttonPanel) 
    ## Set Default actions for the buttons 
    $form.AcceptButton = $okButton          # ENTER = Ok 
    $form.CancelButton = $cancelButton      # ESCAPE = Cancel 

    return $form
}


$LeftMargin = 25
$BottomMargin = 30
$i = 0


$form = Build-FormPanel "Please update server configurations"

foreach($param in $hash){#Where $hash is an "dictionary" of key/value pairs

    $k = $param.Key
    $v = $param.Value

    $lblValue = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label   
    $lblValue.Text = $k+":"  
    $lblValue.Top = 20*$i ; $lblValue.Left = $LeftMargin; $lblValue.Width=150 ;$lblValue.AutoSize = $true 
    $form.Controls.Add($lblValue)    # Add to Form 
    # 
    $txtValue = New-Object Windows.Forms.TextBox  
    $txtValue.Top = 20*$i; $txtValue.Left = 160; $txtValue.Width = 320;  
    $txtValue.Text = $v
    $form.Controls.Add($txtValue)    # Add to Form 
    $i++
}


$form.Topmost = $True
$form.Add_Shown( { $form.Activate(); } ) 
$result = $form.ShowDialog() 


if($result -eq "OK") 
    {   
        $j = 0;
        foreach($param in $hash){
            ${"txtValue_$j"}.Text 
            $j++
        }

} 
else {Write-Host "Cancel"}
```

Basically, this works OK to display the form and inputs. But after submission, I am unable to capture all the user inputs. Only the last input value is captured, obviously because the variables get overwritten in the loop.

How can I achieve capturing the data as described?

Answer (score 0):

The issue as you have mentioned is because of the its getting overwritten.
I can give you a logical set off.

YOu can use it in a loop and in the loop , you store all the data either in **array** or if its dynamic then you can use **arraylist** by using

> New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

. But recommended is to create **PSCustomObject** , store in that and add that to the arraylist each time.

Finally you can get the output captured in the arraylist. 
Further you can try making the arraylist *Global*  so that it will be available for the entire script.

Hope it helps.